# Introducing an alias in technical literature

Tags: writing-style, tech-writing

In technical literature (namely, a requirements document), what is an appropriate way of introducing an alias which is used from there on; instead of the full, completely-defined term?

I'm looking for a short, concise way of expressing it, without sounding archaic (like `henceforth`) or informal (like `AKA`).

I know I can use the "Definitions" or "Glossary" section (and I'll be sure to add it there also), but I want the text to be as self-contained as possible.

Comment: *Henceforth*, like *hereafter*, is formal, and *[hereinafter](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/64944)* especially legalistic-sounding, but I wouldn't call them [archaic](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/archaic-words).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The *really really big word* (called *biggie* ***hereafter***), is our main concern. Now, biggie is...

Instead of `called`, you can use `referred to as`/`known as`

Instead of `hereafter`, you can use `for the rest of this book/chapter/document` etc.

Answer (score 2):

In my documentation (I'm a software developer), I make sure to solve this in several ways, as it depends on what type of person is reading the document.

Mentioning it at every occurence defeats the purpose of having an abbreviation, but only mentioning it once makes it hard to find the definition.

**Disclaimer**:
I've never heard complaints about my documentation, but this is more or less a personal way of doing it, I'm not aware of any standardized approaches.

- At the first mention of the thing, I add its abbreviation in parentheses.

  "To make sure everything works with the Company Application Thingy (CAT), ..."

This helps people who are reading the entire document, as the definition is placed where they will first encounter it.

- I also add in a Glossary (usually after the contents table, but before the actual document). This is to help people who are skimming through the document, by providing an easy list to look up any abbreviations, without them having to find its first occurrence in the document.

For infrequently used abbreviations, I like to hyperlink them to their Glossary definitions, although that may be too cumbersome in large scale documentation.
If otherwise phrased ambiguously (Suppose the Company Application Thingy (CAT) has a troubleshooting section on cats messing with its workflow), I will put an abbreviation in bold and/or capitals to point toward it being a glossary entry.

- I tend to also specifically add abbreviation definitions to headings if they contain the full name. Unless brevity is needed, I will always make a heading like:

  "Installing the Company Application Thingy (CAT)"

This functions as a sort of "quick glossary", so the reader knows the meaning of CAT if he's only reading that chapter/paragraph.

---

**Edit - Forgot to add**

In regards to phrasing it (AKA/henceforth), I choose to not use any of those words if it's easily derived from the context and placement of the parentheses.

Company Application Thingy (CAT).

If it's less obvious, I capitalize the letters of the abbreviation and potentially add a phonetic representation should it have a (non-obvious) one.

Company APplication Thingy (CAPT, "captain").

Meaning to imply it's pronounced "captain" in spoken language, like how SQL is generally pronounced "sequel" instead of spelling the letters.

Comment: +1 for the "Glossary ... before the actual document", this makes sense in context of technical documentation.

Comment: I do nearly the exact same thing as @Flatter.  I put the full name of proprietary abbreviations at the first mention on each self-contained unit of information:  web page, knowledge base article, section in a manual.  If material is removed from the context, there is still a definition of the abbreviation.  Industry standard abbreviations are defined only on pages discussing them specifically and in the glossary.