# Need help with repetitive use of a company name

Tags: grammar, expressions

I have a question regarding a report I'm preparing for a company. Since I'm not affiliated with the company, I have to refer to them in the third person. In this case, do I need to use the company's name every time or can I just use **the company**?

For example, let's say the company is Apple. Should it be:

> *Apple is _______. Apple is also _______. Apple aims to _______.*

Or:

> *Apple is _______. The company is also _______. The company
>   aims to _______.*

Comment: _Apple is a tech giant. **It** sells smartphones._

Comment: _When you (hereafter, the buyer) purchase this product, ..._ See also. http://english.stackexchange.com/q/64944/50044

Comment: The report's title will have the name of the company, and the report is about the company, so why would you need to bludgeon your readers with the name of the company each and every time the company is the subject of a sentence?

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't need to say the name of the company every time. To promote readability, **vary your sentence structure to alleviate the burden of "the company" as the subject.** Let's use Apple as the model. I know nothing of the tech industry.

> Apple is now a monolith of a company. In the 1970s, it struggled to distinguish itself from its nearest competitors such as IBM and Radio Shack. However, in the 1980s, the Macintosh computer became known as the most trouble-free computer in the business. Although the cost of this product was prohibitive to some, and others complained it wasn't as user-friendly as Windows by Microsoft, the ability of Apple to meet and exceed its customers' expectations created an explosion of interest. Because of proper research and development, the company brought new gadget after new gadget to a throng of devoted buyers, leading Apple to become one of the leaders in the tech industry.

Answer (score -2):

I believe it is better to simply use the company name over and over.

It is a type of alliteration and anaphora to use the company name over and over. It is used as a poetic device for emphasis and dramatic effect. For example, in Martin Luther King Jr famous speech, he uses the phrase, "I had a dream" to emphasize and bring focus to the topic of his dream. I believe if you use the company name over and over, it could have this alliteration and anaphora effect.

Comment: It might not be easy to slip into Stu's style but it would be much more useful than repeating the company name over and over.

Spend more time listening to TV adverts - yes, I know that sounds odd - and you will see how many and many a phrase which 'seems' perfectly correct, simply doesn't work…

If repeating the company was alliteration or anaphora it could be very powerful; since it's actually neither, it will work as a powerful wet blanket, successfully deadening any interest in your report.

If you're presenting bullet point in PowerPoint, that's different and otherwise, take care.